# Updating a dynamic chart while running a macro - Animated Graph in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, animation, charts

I have a dynamic chart that gets updated for hourly data, based on a cell value. That cell is controlled by a scroll button or entering the date manually in another cell. Take a look at the gif below for an insight;

[image]

What I want to do is updating the chart using VBA to make it like an animation. Let's have this (pseudo-)code below;

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    '64 bit Excel
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" ( _
        ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#Else
    '32 bit Excel
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" ( _
        ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#End If

Sub Animate()

On Error GoTo Error ErrorHandler    

Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AChart")   
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

For i = 1 to 3000
    Sleep 50
    wsh.Range("K4").Value = i
    DoEvents
    Application.Wait Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
Next i

Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description & " Procedure Animated Graph"

End Sub
```

This (particularly `DoEvents`)  does not make the graph update on the screen. I wanted to know if there's a way to implement this.

Comment: Your best bet would be `Application.Ontime`. `Sleep` and other stuff dont work well, because VBA is still running so it interferes with the Excel application. Try `Ontime` and tell us, you know how to use it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`Application.OnTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx)** can be used for this purpose. Other things like `DoEvents` or `Sleep` will still have the macro running and that prevents the chart to be updated (on the screen).

## How to make a dynamic graph?

First, for the sake of completion, this is a link to how to make a dynamic graph:

***[Dynamic Excel Charts](https://excelcharts.com/animation-interaction-and-dynamic-excel-charts/)***

Here, you learn to refer to a cell and use offset (or similar approaches) to change the data that appears on your chart.

## How to automate changes in the chart?

The code below is one of my early tries for automation of updating chart data (so called, "animating"). `Start` and `Finish` are two `Command Buttons` in the sheet that user can control the "Dynamic Graph" by them. You can play around and make `Pause`, etc. as you need but this would give a raw idea about how to implement this:

```
Public laststop As Boolean
Public i As Integer

Sub start()
    laststop = True 'This controls schedule in Application.Ontime

    i = 1 'Reset the date to the first entry each time you press start
    Call Animate 'calls the main sub
End Sub

Sub finish()
    laststop = False 'Set the schedule to false to stop the macro
End Sub

'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
'XXX MAIN PROGRAM XXX
'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Sub Animate()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Application.OnTime Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2), "Animate", Schedule:=laststop

If Not laststop Then GoTo nextline

Dim wsh As Worksheet

Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dynamic_Graph")
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

wsh.Range("I34").Value = i + 1
DoEvents

i = i + 1

If i > 200 Then laststop = False 'last data entry
   

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

   'Sometimes after running the finish macro these errors are happening that _
   'we don't want users to see them as they don't affect the process

If Err.Description = "The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type" _
Or Err.Description = "Method 'OnTime' of object '_Application' failed" _ 
Then GoTo nextline

MsgBox Err.Description & " #Procedure: Animated Graph"

nextline:
         laststop = False

End Sub
```

Thanks to [@A.S.H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4926357/a-s-h) for suggesting `OnTime`.

Answer (score -1):

I have an easier way of doing it, IMHO. Like M-M I set up a table using "offset" references so i only need to change one cell (AI1, which I call my control cell) to get the right data into my bar graph. The problem is that the graph will not update unless it thinks there is a change to the graph. So, each time I make a change, I reset GapWidth to the same value. (This is a parameter of the bar graph.)

```
' This creates the sleep function, leave it as it is
#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    '64 bit Excel
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" ( _
        ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#Else
    '32 bit Excel
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" ( _
        ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#End If

'this is my macro
Sub RunAnimation()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Range("AI1").Select 'this 
    For i = 1 To 24
        Sleep 1000 'milliseconds
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = i 'update the value in my control cell
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate 'chart 1 is the object's name
        ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 93
        Range("AI1").Select 'i go back to my control cell to deselected the chart
    Next i
End Sub
```

Before running this you should position the screen how you want it. The control cell should be on the screen (make the text white to make it invisible). It is not an intelligent script. If you have multiple charts you have to do the ActiveSheet... and ActiveChart... lines once for each. If you don't know the names of the charts record a macro and click on each one to get them.

You can use `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))` instead of `sleep 1000`, then you don't need that first section. However I do not know if you can do fractions of a second.

Comment: `sleep` and `Application.Wait` don't work!